# Difference in size when converting UILabel to UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics, uilabel

I am drawing a UILabel to a UIImage.
The UILabel has a width of 193.5 while the resulting UIImage from the code below is 194 wide.
 Why is this?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[label.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

How'd you manage to get half a pixel in the width of a UILabel?  It probably saw that and rounded it up automatically to 194.

Comment: Just tossing it out there: iOS *does* have two different concepts for sizing: points vs. pixels, with the most common distinction being that on retina displays, 1 "point" is 2x2 pixels. I'm not sure how exactly that plays into the interaction we are being asked about here, but it may help to know it's out there.

Comment: Partially.  If you're on a retina display you'll still reference it as a non-retina dimension (i.e. - 320 rather than 640).  The device will automatically multiply those dimensions by 2 if it has a retina display but in code you should still reference it as non-retina sizes.  Therefore half pixels would still not be rendered as only whole pixels can.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this - there is no way really to render half a pixel. I guess you could technically blend one pixel with another, but you still need a full pixel there. So it has to round up. I'd consider it a mistake to have a non-integer value for your any UI element coordinate - you'll end up with a blurry looking UI. So try to figure out how to fix the half-pixel issue.